# Client-server real-time audio streaming

Tags: udp, client-server, real-time, audio-streaming, rtsp

I'm trying to develop a client/server realtime audio processing application. The client sends streaming audio to the server, the server sends the modified streaming audio to the client. A small delay is important to me, so the TCP is not suitable as a transport protocol.

Right now I'm using gRPC, but the delay is big. I tried to find a project similar to gRPC, but with UDP, but didn't find it. I don't have the resources to make a good framework using UDP. Then I learned about RTSP (RTP), but didn't understand if it can be used in bidirectional streaming. Help with the right direction for me. Recommend open source projects (or not) if they exist. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use WebRTC?  The whole stack is designed around low latency applications.

Comment: I'm currently using Python on both the backend and frontend. Frontend is a desktop application. If WebRTC can be used similarly, but without browser, then I will try. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, yes.  There are some hefty libraries to import and work with, but yes it's possible and done regularly.

Comment: I found aiortc. It seems it can be used for client and server. It won't be easy. Thank you.